# Errors when importing with pip due to PYTHONPATH on ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, pythonpath

I've been following [this](http://bathompso.com/blog/Flask-AWS-Setup/) tutorial and it states that

> The $PYTHONPATH variable seems to get unset randomly, and causes errors for later steps.

and then to add the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat'
```

I did this and then tried to install a bunch of pip packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

I get a load of errors when installing all the packages, this can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/sBYVnusE).

I think this relates to the issue with PYTHONPATH. Why do I receive this error and what can be done so that I get no errors when using python and pip? Thanks.

Edit:

After trying dragster's answer I run the application. However I receive the error `ImportError: No module named regex` as a python library [awesome-slugify](https://github.com/dimka665/awesome-slugify) contains a python file that imports the regex library which is part of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these set of commands -

- sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
- sudo apt-get install python-dev
- pip install --upgrade setuptools
- Run your required pip command

Hope this works :)

Comment: Thanks this works great for installing packages but I still have issues with using them. I edited the question to show my issue.

Comment: @PavSidhu - you need to install the regex library to solve this. Issue these commands - sudo apt-get install python-dev && easy_install regex

Comment: @PavSidhu were you able to overcome the issue?

Comment: Using `sudo apt-get install python-dev worked perfectly. I then used  virtualenv to install all my other packages. ` Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had done something like this. Try running the same pip command with administrative privilege using sudo. It worked for me.

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the same errors as in the pastebin.

Comment: @PavSidhu Try issuing this command first - pip install --upgrade setuptools